# implement a data structure for my program

Tags: java, data-structures

Need to create a program which allows users to enter the number of players, edit those player scores, find individual player scores or view the entire score list.

I have gone through several data structures and Hash Tables seem like the best choice here. However I haven't been able to fully grasp how to build one and what my other alternatives are in this situation.

I've tried using 2 Dimensional Arrays but they can't be edited so it creates problems. Trees don't help either. My options right now are either linked lists or hash tables.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Springfield Golf Club\nSelect an Option\n    1) Enter Scores\n    2) Find Golfer\n    3) Display Scoreboard\n    4) Exit");
        try {
            userChoice = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine()); //Main menu select option
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid option");
            continue;
        }

        switch (userChoice) {

            case 1:
                // Do Something
                System.out.println("1 Works");
                if (firstTime == true) {
                    System.out.println("How many players will be playing?");
                    player.setPlayCount(Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine()));
                    String[] GolferInfo =new String[player.getPlayCount()];
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Please enter player name");
                        for(int i = 0; i<player.getPlayCount();i++) {
                            GolferInfo[i] = userInput.nextLine();
                            player.setPlayCount(Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine()));
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a proper number");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Build a table? Why not just use `Map<String, Player>`? Assuming there is a relevant `String` key to be had. Aside: if there are a fixed number of players ("enter the number of players"), and said number is small enough, there is probably nothing wrong with an array. I suspect the larger issue not modeling the `Player` as an object, not the array vs. table question.

Comment: Im just starting with Java so this might not make sense....

Comment: @KevinO I didn't really think of that. Thank you. I'll give this a try